# Change object on client side or on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization, client-server

I'm not sure what is the best practice.
I have some big and complex objects (NOT flat).
In that object I have many related objects - for example Invoice is the main class and one of it's properties is invoiceSupervisor - a big class by it's own called User.
User can also be not flat and have department property - also an object called Department.

For example I want create new Invoice.

First way:
I can present to client several fields to fill in. Some of them will be combos that I will need to fill with available values. For example available invoiceSupervisors. Then all the chosen values I can send to server and on server I can create new Invoice and assign all chosen values to that new Invoice. Then I will need to assign new supervisor I will pull the chosen User by id that user picked up on server from combobox. I might do some verification on the User such as does the user applicable to be invoice supervisor. Then I will assign the User object to invoiceSupervisor. Then after filling all properties I will save the new invoice.

Second way:
In the beginning I can call to server to get a new Invoice. Then on client I can fill all chosen values , for example I can call to server to get new User object and then fill it's id from combobox and assign the User as invoiceSupervisor. After filling the Invoice object on client I can send it to server and then the server will save the new invoice. Before saving server can run some validations as well.

So what is the best approach - to make the object on client and send it to server or to collect all values from client and to make a new object on server using those values ?

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of complexity of your business processing.

What you need is the client creates a new invoice. To do this, the client provides several different input parameters, calls the process and gets the response. This is your first scenario. Simple and clear.

On the other hand, the second approach involves a communication protocol - give me this, I give you something as a response, then give me something else. This sounds unreasonably complicated. You'd have to carefully inspect what happens when the communication breaks at some point. Should a distributed transaction be involved? If yes, do you really need such complexity?

I would opt then for the first scenario. You don't unnecessarily complicate the contract between the client and the server.

Comment: I tend to agree with you . In my company there'd been some debate regarding the issue . Those who likes the second way claim it's "cleaner" this way . In the second option one big object is being transferred between client and server in oppose to several - sometimes 10-15 values that needs to be transferred from client to server if first way is chosen.